# Struggles understanding the derivation of the Householder's method

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder%27s_method) on Householder's method for root-finding derives it in their first approach with:

[image: First step]

I understand this first part.

They continue by saying:

*"The coefficient of degree $d$ has the value ${\displaystyle C\,a^{-d}}$. Thus, one can now reconstruct the zero $a$ by dividing the coefficient of degree $d − 1$ by the coefficient of degree $d$. **Since this geometric series is an approximation to the Taylor expansion of $1/f(x)$**, one can get estimates of the zero of $f(x)$ – now without prior knowledge of the location of this zero – by dividing the corresponding coefficients of the Taylor expansion of $1/f(x)$ or, more generally, $1/f(b+x)$."*

This is the part that makes no sense to me. When they say "this" geometric series, I assume they mean the one shown in the first picture, but their claim that it is approximately equal to the Taylor expansion of a general $1/f(x)$ form I can't understand. I attempted to  expand $1/f(x)$, centered around $a$, and at the second derivative term had already arrived at a very lengthy and ugly expression - how it is almost equal to the geometric series shown in the image is something I need help with.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that explanation very hard to understand, to be honest.

Here's another try:

$$\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{x-a}{f(x)} \frac{1}{x-a} \\
= -\frac{1}{a} \frac{x-a}{f(x)} \frac{1}{1-x/a} \\
= -\frac{1}{a} \frac{x-a}{f(x)} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )^n$$

if $|x|<|a|$.

Now suppose you have chosen to stop everything at degree $n$, then you should in principle expand $\frac{x-a}{f(x)}$ up to degree $n$ also. If you do that, you get

$$\frac{1}{f(x)}= \\
-\frac{1}{a}
\cdot \left ( \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} g^{(k)}(0)  x^k + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} g^{(n+1)}(\xi(x)) x^{n+1} \right ) 
\cdot \left ( \sum_{k=0}^n \left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )^k + \frac{\left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )^{n+1}}{1-x/a} \right )$$

using the Lagrange remainder in the first expansion, and where $g(x)=\frac{x-a}{f(x)}$.

So now what is the true coefficient of degree $x^j$ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$, for $j=0,1,\dots,n$? It is

$$c_j=-\frac{1}{a} \sum_{k=0}^j \frac{1}{k!} \left ( \frac{1}{a} \right )^{j-k} g^{(k)}(0).$$

The idea of Householder expansion is that as $a \to 0$, the dominant term in this sum is the $k=0$ term, since it has the highest power of $1/a$.

Anyway, if this approximation is good then it suggests $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$ should be approximately $\frac{-\frac{1}{a^{n+1}} g(0)}{-\frac{1}{a^{n+2}} g(0)}=a$, and so you can use this ratio (obtained by actually differentiating $\frac{1}{f}$) as an approximation of $a$. To deal with $a$ not close to $0$, you can replace $x$ by $b+x$ where $b \approx a$.

This method of analysis doesn't actually expose any advantage of large $n$; it ostensibly implies $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=a+O(a^2)$ regardless of what $n$ is. You need a somewhat more sophisticated mode of attack (for example what is described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder%27s_method#Derivation) to see why large $n$ has any advantages.

Comment: I’m afraid I understand this answer even less than the Wikipedia one... where did your expansions come from, where did Xi come from, and why does the derivation stop at the second derivative - doesn’t Householder’s method extend to any derivative depth?

Comment: @IdioticShrike Is this any better? (Just to be clear, I was going to any derivative depth the whole time, but for the examination of the leading order asymptotic behavior of the coefficients, you don't actually need any derivatives past the first one.)

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer, but resign myself to needing more education before I can begin to fully appreciate what you’ve written - I may look on this in a year’s time! The expansion of $\frac{x-a}{f(x)}$ to “degree” N went to a completely blown up complex expression that assumes steps of reasoning that I cannot see or pattern-recognise...

Comment: (And why the bars with x=0 and z=xi? That only resembles integral notation to me)

Comment: @IdioticShrike The sum is just the Taylor expansion; the "extra" term is just the Lagrange remainder, which hopefully you're acquainted with as it is rather widely used in numerical methods. I generally don't like to write $\approx$. As for the bars, that is just showing evaluation points for the derivative. You could use parentheses for the evaluation instead.

Comment: @IdioticShrike I changed some notation, maybe it is easier to understand now.

Comment: That is much clearer thank you! I am confused why the sum of $\frac{x}{a}$ was expanded to include the $(\frac{x}{a})^{n+1}$ over what looks like the denominator for a geometric series... the sums of $\frac{x}{a}$ are already written like that as the expansion of a geometric series' sum.

Comment: I understand the derivation of $c_j$: does the ratio $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$ leave us with an expression that looks like the textbook derivative form for Householder's method?

Comment: @IdioticShrike The $\left ( \frac{x}{a} \right )^{n+1}$ term is just the remainder from truncating the geometric series; I just wrote it that way since we do know exactly what it is, so there is no need for a Lagrange remainder expression or similar. The ratio $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}$, obtained from expansion of $\frac{1}{f}$, is what Householder's method actually uses.